# First time open Onboarding Screen should be the .LAUNCHER on the manifest?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, manifest, launch

I'm trying to make an Android app that has a Onboarding Screen that should teach the user how to use the app. I want to show this screen only the first time the app is opened. My Main Activity have a Navigation Drawer with fragments(recyclerview) and this screen should be shown as launcher once the Onboarding screen was already seen or isn't the first time that the app is opened.

So, the question is: what activity I should select as Launcher in the manifest?

P.S.:Sorry about my bad english in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches to do that. You can create an Activity without layout and name it `DispatcherActivity`. Make this activity as launcher activity.

You can then use `SharedPreferences` to determine if this first launch or subsequent launch (store a boolean `isFirstLaunch`, set it to true as soon as `OnboardingScreen` is launched) in `onCreate` of this activity. If its first launch, then start the `OnboardingActivity` else start  your `MainActivity`.